# Do the users lookup in twitter API v2 free version using endpoints GET /2/users/me

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I write the following code to try the free version of Twitter API v2

```
import requests
import os

# Retrieves the bearer token from the environment variables
bearer_token = os.environ.get("BEARER_TOKEN")
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {bearer_token}',
}
url = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/users/me'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# Prints the JSON response
print(response.json())
```

However, I got error message

```
{'title': 'Unsupported Authentication', 'detail': 'Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only is forbidden for this endpoint.  Supported authentication types are [OAuth 1.0a User Context, OAuth 2.0 User Context].', 'type': 'https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/unsupported-authentication', 'status': 403}
```

I thought this should not require User Context Authentication. If it does require, how should I modify my code.

I do try

```
consumer_key = os.environ["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
consumer_secret = os.environ["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET"]
access_token = os.environ["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
access_token_secret = os.environ["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"]

# Authenticate using the keys
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Create an API class object
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

However, i dont know how to connects these two parts.

Comment: You need to create an auth URL, visit it on a browser and give consent. Then, Twitter will call your callback url. You should request an access token using the code passed in by Twitter in the request that is made to your callback url.